# IF condition gives me warning : always true

Tags: android, if-statement, warnings

I have used **`onNavigationItemSelected`** to display selected item in **NavigationView.**

I dont want to select any items and keep previously selected items as selected **If user select SHARE or RATE from NavigationView**, I wrote following condition for that like:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // update highlighted item in the navigation menu
    mNavMenuItemId = item.getItemId();

    if(mNavMenuItemId != R.id.nav_rate || mNavMenuItemId != R.id.nav_share)
        item.setChecked(true);
}
```

but It gives me warning like:

[image]

## **Edited:**

I have following Menu Items:

[image]
Why is it so? How can I simplify that one?

Comment: how many navigation items do yo have?

Comment: As updated my question, I have 7 items in menu

Answer (score 1):

Probably you meant && instead of ||.

If mNavMenuItemId != R.id.nav_rate is false, then mNavMenuItemId == R.id.nav_rate. It is the only case when the second part of your condition is calculated. Obviously, if it is so, then mNavMenuItemId != R.id.nav_share.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is always true.  There's 3 possibilities:  mNavMenuItemId is nav_rate, its nav_share, or its neither.  If its nav_rate, the second check becomes true.  If its nav_share, the first is true.  If its neither, then both are true.  There's no way for it to be false.

I think you meant && instead of ||

Comment: **If its neither, then both are true.** How?

Comment: Um simple math? If rate is 5 and share is 7, let's say the item is 11. In that case the item is not 5 so the first is true, and not 7 so the second is true

Answer (score 0):

Its simply logic: Your If condition says "If the ID isnt this or isnt that, do code in brackets" But this is a condition that always will be true, because if the ID is the same like one in the condition, it cant be the same like the other (!=) and if it isnt like both of them, the condition is true too. So u have to change the extender "||"-> OR to "&&"-> AND. I hope you understood, what I wanted to explain. If you have any other question to that problem, just ask.

Greetings from Germany